# Parts of the question as answers?

Tags: discussion, questions

So I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28885214/3897302) question earlier today and I noticed that it seemed like the user had posted different parts of their question as answers to the question.

I flagged for moderator attention with the comment "User posting question parts as answers". As of now it is still active, but I am wondering if this was the right action. I have never seen or heard of this type of situation so I figured a moderator would be the best choice to handle it.

Should I have just downvoted? As of now the question has 0 downvotes and it doesn't really seem to be off topic, the main issue is the formatting. I considered flagging with a different reason as well but nothing else seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You're right: those replies look like they should be edits to the question instead. In that user's defense, another user had posted an answer asking them to show their code (which has since been removed) — and this other user had more than enough rep to post comments (!), so they were not setting a good example for the new user at all.

I have converted those answers into edits. Thanks for your flag. You are correct in that this is something that is best handled by a moderator — while other users are able to manually edit the content from these answers into the question, and, [with higher privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), vote to delete the answers, a moderator is able to do all of these things with a click of a button.